# WS response parse to html table

Tags: javascript, python, django, web-services

I have a view where I request some info from a web service. I am trying to show the response (xml) as a html table. For this I am using json2html library.

```
def LeerXMLView(request):
    with open("/home/pyc/DjangoProjects/xmlcbs/media/prueba.xml","r") as archivo:
         request_data = archivo.read()

    target_url = "http://1.1.1.1/services/testservice?wsdl"
    headers = {'Content-type':'text/xml'}
    data_response = requests.post(target_url, data=request_data, headers=headers).text
    jdato = xmltodict.parse(data_response)
    data = json2html.convert(json = jdato)
    return render_to_response('prueba.html',{'data':data_template})
```

In the template is displayed as raw text, even when the json2html library add the necessary html tag to print a html table

How can I show the output as a html table instead of plain text in my template

I don't know how to handle the response of the web service to show the data as an html table.

I am not sure I am using in the correct way the json2html lib.

Any advice

Comment: I love python as much as the next guy, but is there a real reason that you need to go from xml to python dict to json to html? Seems a little convoluted to me. XSLT is usually how this would be done. lxml has [XSLT support](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt).

Comment: @iLoveTux, I know is very convoluted. But I have an issue trying to install lxml and until I resolve the issue I need to display the data in some readable and organized way. For that reason I was trying with other libs. But you are right the best way is lxml. I will try to fix my issue. Thanks for your reply. Thanks